# Angular no me deja acceder a las propiedades de un objeto

Tags: angular

Hola estoy intentando acceder a la propiedad {{pedido.activo}} de este objeto en una vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y me da el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objeto existe porque cuando aplico el (pipe|json) a pedido {{pedido|json}} me lo muestra en la vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código debe ir en formato texto. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia las imágenes por texto. También puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad `activo` está dentro del objeto `cuenta` del objeto `pedido`.

El acceso tendría que ser así:

```
pedido?.cuenta.activo
```

Se usa el operador `?` para evitar errores en caso se quiera acceder a las propiedades del objeto `pedido` cuando este todavía no tenga un valor.